# org.hibernate.HibernateException: Could not find datasource

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I am using JPA with Hibernate implementation and i have created a datasource in websphere server. I am trying to access this datasource in my JPA application. But, when i try to access , i am getting the below exception . Please help me out if you have come across such situation. Thanks

org.hibernate.HibernateException: Could not find datasource
Caused by: 
javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name comp/env/jdbc not found in context "java:".

Please find the below details:
Datasource Name: pieportaldev_0
JNDI Name: pie/logDB 
And my Persistance.xml is

http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd" version="1.0">

```
<provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
<!-- the JNDI data source -->
<jta-data-source>java:comp/env/jdbc/pieportaldev_0</jta-data-source>
<class>com.test.jpa.UserInfo</class>
<properties>
  <!-- if this is true, hibernate will print (to stdout) the SQL it executes, so you can check it to ensure it's not doing anything crazy -->
 <!--  <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" /> -->
  <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true" />
  <!-- since most database servers have slightly different versions of the SQL, Hibernate needs you to choose a dialect so it knows the subtleties of talking 
    to that server -->
  <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect" />
  <!-- this tell Hibernate to update the DDL when it starts, very useful for development, dangerous in production -->
  <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />
</properties>
```

Comment: Where you define env/jdbc/pieportaldev_0?

Comment: You need to modify the jta-data-source tag in persistence.xml in order to match the dataSource JNDI name.